# Cookies from cross domain are not accessible in iframe

Tags: iframe, cookies, cross-platform

I searched for my requirements and found answers for my question. But I could not make it work. Hence I thought of posting my requirements here.

My website is hosted by a third party vendor and I do not have control over their servers.
I have an iframe set in one of their html pages. This iframe will point to my server and I should be able to access a cookie set by the vendor in their main page. To try this I created two html pages. One would be named as SetCookie.html and the other one would be GetCookie.html. Both reside in different computers. Please find the source code below:

**SetCookie.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Set Cookie</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function setCookie() {
                var cookieValue = document.getElementById("txtCookie").value;
                var cookieName = "TestCookie";
                document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue;
                document.getElementById("tdCookieMessage").innerHTML = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + " is set!";
            }
        </script>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Cookie
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtCookie" value="" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="btnGetCookie" onclick="setCookie();" value="Set Cookie!" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" id="tdCookieMessage">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <iframe src="http://myServer/GetCookie.html"></iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**GetCookie.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Get Cookie</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getCookie(cookieName) {
            var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
            for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
                x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
                y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
                x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
                if (x == cookieName) {
                    document.getElementById("tdCookie").innerHTML = unescape(y);
                    expireCookie(cookieName);
                }
            }
        }
        function expireCookie(cookieName) {
            document.cookie = cookieName + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btnGetCookie" onclick="getCookie('TestCookie');" value="Test Cookie Value is: " />
            </td>
            <td id="tdCookie">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Only cookies that are set for the domain that the page is on will be sent to the page.  IE you are on mywebsite.com, and they are on theirdomain.com, you will not receive their cookies, and they will not receive yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only cookies that are set for the domain that the page is on will be sent to the page. IE you are on mywebsite.com, and they are on theirdomain.com, you will not receive their cookies, and they will not receive yours.  This is how cookies work, for security reasons.

You could get around this if both yours and the vendor's sites were on the same domain, then you could share cookies between the applications.

IE them.mywebsite.com and me.mywebsite.com would both receive the cookies for *.mywebsite.com.